# RecursionError : maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Tags: python, django

I am getting an error in admin console while trying to open a model . How to fix it

Model.py

```
class TbSysEmailconfig(models.Model):
    id = models.ForeignKey('self', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='Id', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    emailtemplateid = models.ForeignKey(TbMasEmailtemplate, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='EmailTemplateId')
    emailfromname = models.CharField(db_column='EmailFromName', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    emailfrom = models.CharField(db_column='EmailFrom', max_length=100)
    credential = models.CharField(db_column='Credential', max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(db_column='Password', max_length=100)
    post = models.IntegerField(db_column='Post', blank=True, null=True)
    host = models.CharField(db_column='Host', max_length=100)
    priority = models.CharField(db_column='Priority', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    maximumday = models.IntegerField(db_column='MaximumDay', blank=True, null=True)
    maximumminute = models.IntegerField(db_column='MaximumMinute', blank=True, null=True)
    systemid = models.IntegerField(db_column='SystemId')
    partfiletemplate = models.CharField(db_column='PartFileTemplate', max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    comment = models.CharField(db_column='Comment', max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    ismaildefault = models.SmallIntegerField(db_column='IsMailDefault')
    maildefault = models.CharField(db_column='MailDefault', max_length=4000, blank=True, null=True)
    createddate = models.DateTimeField(db_column='CreatedDate')
    createdbyuserid = models.IntegerField(db_column='CreatedByUserId')
    updateddate = models.DateTimeField(db_column='UpdatedDate')
    updatedbyuserid = models.IntegerField(db_column='UpdatedByUserId')
    delflag = models.SmallIntegerField(db_column='DelFlag')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'TB_SYS_EmailConfig'
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .model import TbSysEmailconfig 
#Modifire 
admin.site.register(TbSysEmailconfig)
```

[image]

When I select some item
it show this error

[image]

Comment: Why is your primary key a self-referential foreign key? That would probably be your issue

Comment: thank for answer , how to fix this issue ? join table ? @Iain Shelvington

Answer (score 1):

Remove the id field from your model, as you have referenced it as a foreign key to the model itself. The id field is automatically generated if no field in the model is explicitly chosen.